# Предотвращение дефолтного поведения браузера

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, http-redirect

Использую для разработки ASP.NET MVC5.
Появилась необходимость на странице, выводящей результаты запроса, данные для которого берутся из HTML-формы, предотвратить стандартное поведение браузера при нажатии клавиши F5, чтобы вместо выведения запроса о повторной отправке формы, клиент перенаправлялся на другой ресурс по жёстко указанному URI. Не очень силён в javascript.

Comment: никак - при пост запросе - можете попробовать get метод. Можете вашу разметку показать и код куда форма отправляется и как определять куда редиректить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел вот такой тривиальный выход из ситуации: при добавлении нижеприведенного javascript-кода на страницу, производится редирект по указанному URL, вместо обновления, при нажатии на F5:

```
function disableF5(e) {         
    if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = window.location.href.toString();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
});
```